# Обработка сигналов в многопоточной программе

Tags: unix, c++, pthread

Всем добрый день!
Господа профессионалы, разрешите пожалуйста мои сомнения : многопоточной программе приходят сигналы SIGCHLD от порожденных процессов, и хотелось бы, чтобы их обработка произовдилось в основном потоке выполнения, а не в дочерних. В литературе оговаривается, что сигнал доставляется одному произвольному потоку, в то же время есть функция `pthread_sigmask()`, которая может заблокировать доставку сигнала конкретному потоку. Могу ли я, установив блокировку для данного сигнала в дочерних потоках, добиться того, чтобы обработку осуществлял только основной поток, или это вызовет потерю приходящих сигналов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можете. Именно так и надо делать.

Обработчик сигнала вызывается в произвольном "незаблокированном" потоке.

Comment: @avp, Спасибо!